# How to enforce capitalisation on users First Name and Last Name

Tags: users

We have developed a Craft 3 site that has user registration. Once a user account has been confirmed and activated, they are shown in a Contacts directory, which other users can search through.

As the user is responsible for adding their own details, a few users have submitted their names in lowercase:

`jamie wade` instead of `Jamie Wade`.

Whilst there is nothing *wrong* with this, it doesn't look great. Is there anyway we can enforce capitalisation in Craft on the users First Name and Last Name fields?

I am aware of [Twig's title filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/title.html), and this is a good fallback if there isn't anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily add client side (JS) validation before the user registration form is submitted. How to do that depends on your JS architecture, I'd use something like vee-validate with a regex validation.

However it would probably be more user friendly to just automatically do the title casing in a custom module, adding something like the following inside the module's init() function:

```
Event::on(\craft\services\Elements::class, \craft\services\Elements::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) {
    if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\User) {
        $event->element->firstName = \craft\helpers\StringHelper::titleize($event->element->firstName);
        $event->element->lastName = \craft\helpers\StringHelper::titleize($event->element->lastName);
    }
});
```

Just beware if you have international users. Who knows what this will do to their names. See [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Thanks Udo, that sounds reasonable. That blog post is also a real eye-opener, thanks for sharing!